# ThreadPool - How to delete Worker (this) once it's member thread is finished

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, worker

The goal is to implement the Worker which executes tasks in a separate thread. The problem is to design the Worker shutdown path correctly. So:

```
class Worker
{
    /* ... */
    /**
     * @brief Thread pool worker constructor
     *
     * Runs the worker's taskRunner() in the stand alone thread.
    */
    Worker( ThreadPool * threadPool )
    {
        /* Run the task runner in new thread */
        this->mThread = std::thread( std::bind( & Worker::taskRunner, this, threadPool ) );
    }
    /* ... */
};
```

The worker runs it's member method `Worker::taskRunner` in a standalone thread. The taskRunner looks like this (unnecessary stuff removed):

```
void taskRunner( ThreadPool * threadPool )
{
    /* Infinite loop */
    while( this->getState() != State::TERMINATED )
    {
        /* ... */
    }

    /* At this point, the thread is going to be finished */
}
```

Once the infinite loop of the taskRunner is exited I would like to delete the Worker itself which instance is held in `ThreadPool` class in `std::list` collection:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Worker>> mWorkers;
```

I would like to use the `void std::list::remove( const T& value );` method.

**The problem is in which scope this `remove()` is called.**

1. If I call it at the end of the `taskRunner()` method, it is going to
   be executed in scope of the Worker's thread, right? But is it
   correct approach to delete the parent object from it's member
   thread?
2. I also thought about using `boost::signals2::signal` to
   notify the worker object itself it's thread is finished and so the
   Worker can ask the thread pool to remove itself...? Isn't is an
   overkill? Would it be a meaningfull solution to signal between main
   and worker's thread?

In general I would like to avoid any blocking pattern in main thread (where the Worker is running)... 
Many thanks in advance to anyone for any idea how to solve this problem...

Comment: Usually you would pass tasks to the threadpool class, which manages the task queue, assigns tasks to different workers and cleans up when everything is finished. Workers are spawned _once_ and wait for new tasks to arrive. The point of a threadpool is to not have to spawn a new thread for each new task, which can be quite expensive. If you are spawning a new thread with each task, why have a `Worker` class at all?

Comment: @cantordust You are right. The threadpool shall manage a limited amount of workers which fetch the tasks from the queue. This is the principle of thread pool. But what if the tasks are somehow dependent in terms of waiting - one task might wait for another one which is also blocked or not even scheduled. In this case, the solution is to temporarily add another worker who does this job. Once the situation changes, the number of workers is limited again. Long story short the threadpool shall maintain defined amount of active workers not the constant amount of possibly waiting threads.

Comment: I see. Just a suggestion: if some tasks need to wait for others to complete, maybe you could use a priority queue (possibly `std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Worker>>`?). Define the priority in the `Worker` class and give the queue a custom comparator to schedule the workers with the highest priority first. Then, when you pop the queue one task at a time, you will be processing the tasks in order of priority and you can discard the worker immediately after it is finished.

Comment: @cantordust Oh, great idea! But the `std::priority_queue` should be used for the task queue, shouldn't it? The workers are just held in some container (`std::list`) which allows the constant time element insertion and removal from anywhere in the list (that was my criteria to choose)

Comment: `std::list` has constant time insertion and removal of elements, but only if you already have an iterator pointing to the correct element. Otherwise, you would have to traverse the list to the correct place, which is linear time on average. I would suggest `std::unordered_map` as it features constant-time insert, erase and lookup. About priority_queue, I was thinking about `std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Worker>>` or even just `std::priority_queue<Worker>`. `Worker` could have a data member `int priority`, a `std::thread` holding the task and `operator ()` to execute the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some lazy deletion routine using a single housekeeping thread to check the list at a certain interval, and remove the finished Worker object from the list by checking its state by calling Worker::getState().

Comment: You ment to implement another checker thread in the threadPool itself which will continuously poll the workers for it's state and will remove the terminated ones?

Comment: Yes, this kind of implementation is something like JAVA Garbage collection mechanism.

Comment: ...and maybe to make it triggered using `std::condition_variable` to reduce the load... makes sense to me! Many thanks!